# Laravel Pretty URL purgatory

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I've never had this issue before, setting up on a new work machine and getting some odd issues. Firstly I should point out that it was working fine and after making some seemingly unrelated edits the routing without index.php became an issue.
I enabled:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Ive tried a bunch of combinations of this based on stack overflow gthreads. An hour on this seems too long, I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: "the routing without index.php became an issue"  That's pretty vague.  What happens when you try to route with index.php?  A web server 404 page?  A laraval 404 page?  A web server error page?  a laravel error page?  A blank screen? Something else?

Comment: The error page is not the standard laravel error, if I route to an internal view without the index.php I get "Not Found  The requested resource /admin was not found on this server." I think it's an apache error page

Comment: My issues persist and this issue with laravel 4 on mavericks seems to be incredibly prevalent. No common solution just lots of dead ends on peoples stack posts so what the $%#^ ??

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 would be to make sure Apache's rewrites are actually working.  Try creating a file in your web root named `bar.php`

```
#File: bar.php
<p>Hello Bar</p>
```

And then creating the following in your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule foo.php bar.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And then try loading the URI `foo.php` on your server

```
http://mysite.example.com/foo.php
```

If your web server correctly redirects to `bar.php`, then you know Apache's setup correctly.  If it doesn't, it means rewrites aren't on.  Once you know if rewrites are on or off you'll know where to concentrate your debugging.

Comment: I get the laravel error for no route on foo, no redirect. I'm assuming this means mod re writes are not working. Where do I start? I enabled the mod_rewrite in the httpd.conf file. What else can I do?

Comment: @Kevin -- if you're seeing the laravel error page when you load `foo.php` that probably means mod_rewrite is working, and intercepting foo.php

Comment: Ok so the issue is laravel or my htaccess. Which makes sense because I installed from the repo to my other system and am getting the same result. Also its important to note it worked at first and changed after I started working with it. Haven't been able to determine the cause